# After forcing SSRS to show limit number of records in each page, aggregation is getting calculated on each page, instead of whole group

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, grouping, aggregation, page-break

Hello and Please help me! I-m really stuck.

I have a matrix in which exist two groups of Year and Month. So it shows an aggregation of values of matrix based on Year and Month.
This report was slow. That's why I forced this matrix to show 500 records in each page and I have done this by adding a Parent Group and writing an expression for that group.
The problem is that now the aggregation is done at the end of EACH page instead of the end of group.

for example let's say I run the report for the Year of 2019 and the month of November and there are 3000 records of data which are shown in 6 pages. Instead of having the Sum for my values for the whole month of November, the report is calculating and showing the Sum at the end of each page. But I want to have the Sum just when the month changes, so at the end of the month.

Comment: It sounds like you added the parent grouping so your aggregated group is now a child group. Probably need a pic of your design view to see what the deal is. Make sure your table is selected so it shows the grouping on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your group a parent, add your page break group between your last group and your detail.
Make the page break column as small as possible (I have left it wide in my example)

Your layout will look like the images below (for demonstration I have created pages of max 10 rows)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you a lot my friend, your answer gave me an idea how to resolve it, Thank you very much, very much